# IntelliJ IDEA plugin: associating a source psi file with a icon in the package structure

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm building a idea plugin which needs to create source file with the extension of ".java". I have created a file template and used it in an implementation of `JavaCreateTemplateInPackageAction<PsiElement>` class. In the constructor of the above mentioned class I called the constructor of the super class with a icon(which I loaded using `IconLoader.getIcon` before) like this

```
protected JavaCreateTemplateInPackageAction(String text, String description, Icon icon, boolean inSourceOnly) {
    super(text, description, icon, inSourceOnly ? JavaModuleSourceRootTypes.SOURCES : null);
}
```

Finally I registered the implementation in plugin.xml as an action. The code works as a charm to create the source file with given template but the issue is in the package structure it doesn't shows the given custom icon, instead it shows the default icon for java classes(letter 'c'). But the given icon appears in the new menu when right click on the source package to create a source file. Can anybody help me out please.? Thanks.

PS: I tried to change the file extension something other than .java and it still doesn't show the expected icon but instead it shows the generic icon for java(letter 'j' icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon you provide in your `JavaCreateTemplateInPackageAction` is *only* used for that action. Icons in the project view can be overridden using an `IconProvider`, that you can register using the `<iconProvider>` tag in your `plugin.xml`:

```xml
<iconProvider implementation="org.intellij.plugins.ceylon.ide.presentation.CeylonIconProvider"/>
```

Java code:

```java
public class CeylonIconProvider extends IconProvider {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Icon getIcon(@NotNull PsiElement element, int flags) {
        if (element instanceof CeylonFile) {
            return ...
        }

        if (element instanceof CeyLightClass) {
            ...
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```